# how to split gender into two columns as male and female

Tags: sql

I have simple table student which contains two column names and gender as m or f.

I have to count number of male and female in table and display it into tow different columns .

Result should be like:

```
|Male |female |
| 5   |   4   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know `m` but standard SQL for this would be :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE gender WHEN 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male,
    SUM(CASE gender WHEN 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female
FROM student
```

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT SUM(gender='m') AS male, SUM(gender='f') AS female FROM students;`

Explanation: comparison `gender='m'` returns a integer result (1 for match or 0 for nomatch) and sum() adds them up.

Comment: By using this I got result in two rows. There should be only one row

Comment: you messed up something.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(female), COUNT(male) FROM student;
```

This should do it.

edit: I just reread your question and believe you mean there are just a 'name' and a 'gender' column, not a 'male' and a 'female' column. In that case using the SUM() function would work. (as others have already answered)

Comment: how this could do it ? female and male are not columns, there are not even values.

Comment: You are right, I misread the post due to the lack of punctuation. Edited my answer.

Comment: Quick + wrong usually gets more upvotes than slow + correct on here.